# ConTeXt: What are alternatives and rendering setups?

Tags: context, rendering, hooks

I've seen the `alternative` keyword used throughout ConTeXt:

- `\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]`
- `\setupheads[alternative=inmargin]`
- `\setuplist[section][alternative=d]`

I assumed that it was just a popular keyword: an enumeration hardcoded into each macro definition, like:

```
def setuplist(alternative="a", ...):
    if alternative == "a":
        doAlternativeA
    elif alternative == "b":
        doAlternativeB
    elif alternative == "c":
        doAlternativeC
    elif alternative == "d":
        doAlternativeD
```

However the answer to [ConTeXt: avoid enumeration items across pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463045/174577) defines a completely new alternative. This implies that alternatives in ConTeXt are a generic macro hook rather than per-macro keywords.

```
\defineuserdataalternative
  [itemize]
  [renderingsetup=userdata:itemize]

\defineuserdata [item] [alternative=itemize]
```

So what does the `alternative` keyword mean? At what stage is it used or called? What is its scope; what does it do?

Then there is the `renderingsetup` keyword for which I have the same questions. Is it specific to only a subset of ConTeXt macros or is it a generic macro hook? I assume it allows modification of the underlying TeX code before page rendering starts. How does that differ from the usual `command=` keyword? Why must it be defined via an alternative rather than directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `alternative` keyword is commonly used to select between different pre-defined renderings of an element in ConTeXt.  For example `\setuphead[chapter][alternative=middle]` will render chapter titles horizontally centered.

> Is it specific to only a subset of ConTeXt macros or is it a generic macro hook?

Now of course, an alternative requires an implementation which performs the actual rendering.  This is called a rendering setup and should be hidden from the user.  In principle, the `alternative` keyword could select an implementation without the detour via the rendering setup but that would make it much harder to extend.  Hence the modular approach was chosen.  A rendering setup is not generic.  For example a rendering setup which was written for a `\setuphead` alternative cannot be used with `\setupitemize`.  Most setups which offer selection of an alternative support rending setups ([exceptio probat regulam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_that_proves_the_rule)).

> How does that differ from the usual `command=` keyword?

The reason why it is superior to `command=` is that the rendering setup this completely transparent for the user.  Imagine a module which defines additional alternatives for `\setupitemize`.  A user can now use them by simply knowing the additional alternative names.  It therefore blends nicely into the existing interface and “feels” consistent.

> Why must it be defined via an alternative rather than directly?

There is no rule that it *has* to but as I already outlined, it “feels” more consistent.  It probably also makes your code more readable and makes it easier to maintain.

Comment: I don't follow your argument regarding `command=`. If a module defines additional commands, those commands can be used simply by knowing the new names... Perhaps alternatives provides a more consistent interface? I've only seen rendering setups access content via `\getinlineuserdata`. Commands aren't as uniform. Some apply to the entire environment (`\setupitemize`), some apply to specific elements of the environment. Some are passed content via parameters (`\setuppagenumbering`) but most don't have access.

Comment: @user19087 Not every alternative is implemented in terms of userdata.  See for example the head alternatives in [`strc-ren.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/6953b7c4b4c40fab660992622a6fd140fa310b34/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-ren.mkiv#L731-L753).