# ConTeXt: advanced enumeration item setup

Tags: lists, page-breaking, context

This question is a refinement of [ConTeXt: avoid enumeration items across pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463045/174577).

Given an itemgroup, each `\item` contains one or more paragraphs or itemgroups, possibly mixed. I only want pagebreaks between paragraphs or itemgroups, with several exceptions:

- Never page break after the first paragraph, as it is somewhat of a heading
- Only break a paragraph or itemgroup (into pieces) if it is longer than some arbitrary number `X`.
- When breaking a paragraph or itemgroup, ensure that each the length of each portion `Y` is `Y>X/Z` for some arbitrary number `Z`. The idea is to minimize orphans and widows *especially* for the second paragraph which is the main paragraph.

The example below demonstrates the types of paragraphs I'm dealing with.

- Rirst paragraph is always a single line.
- Other paragraphs or nested items are short, 1-5(+?) lines.
- Few paragraphs per item or items per nested itemgroups.

My last two points I considered to be more like guidelines. These are the problems I've been fighting:

- Page break after the first paragraph.
- Poor breaking of the second paragraph. If it's four lines then it is broken 2-2. I don't know if it could be broken 1-3/3-1 and 3-line paragraphs broken 1-2/2-1, or if the widow and club penalties prevent this. I'm not even sure I'd be comfortable having a 5-6 line paragraph broken up at all either. But yeah there's some arbitrary point (8?) were I would want paragraphs split, because horrible page breaks are horrible (and footer spill infinitely worse). When I say second I mean all remaining paragraphs... and that I care about the appearance of the second paragraph more than others. I've been fortunate to not have page breaks across itemgroups, but same guidelines should apply.
- Not comfortable with setting `\widowpenalty` or `\clubpenalty` for the entire document.

```
\setupwhitespace[medium]

\starttext
    \startitemize
    \sym{>}\bold{Heading One}\hfill1

        \samplefile{ward}

    \sym{>}\bold{Heading Two}\hfill2

        \samplefile{ward}

        \samplefile{ward}

    \sym{>}\bold{Heading Three}\hfill3

        \samplefile{knuth}

    \sym{>}\bold{Heading Four}\hfill4

        \startitemize[joinedup,nowhite,after]
            \item Some important point.
            \item \samplefile{jojomayer}
            \item Hmm shouldn't there be whitespace below?
        \stopitemize

        \samplefile{ward}

    \sym{>}\bold{Heading Five}\hfill5

        \samplefile{ward}

        \startitemize[joinedup,nowhite,after]
            \item Some important point.
            \item \samplefile{jojomayer}
            \item Hmm shouldn't there be whitespace below?
        \stopitemize

    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

*(page breaks may occur anywhere)*

Comment: Regarding the source question's answer, I'm under the impression that a `\vbox` would prevent the second paragraph from breaking even when necessary - assuming you could vbox each individual paragraph or itemgroup. And that `\keeplinestogether` doesn't prevent a break after the first paragraph, and can cause nasty orphans/widows when a break is necessary.

Comment: Can you maybe give a real world example of what you are trying to achieve?  For (1) `\starthead{<first par>} <other pars> \stophead` comes to my mind but that does not prevent pagebreaks within `<first par>`.  It could be modified though.  For (2), what if the remaining space on the page is less than `X`?  You will either get a horrible page break or spilling into the footer.  For (3) this is a lot of work to implement.  Basically you'd reimplement TeX's paragraph builder.  To minimize widows and orphans it's easier to tune `\widowpenalty` and `\clubpenalty`.

Comment: In general, forcing or preventing pagebreaks will result in a page that looks torn apart, with enourmos gaps between paragraphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first point you can use `\start...\stophead` with the setup `afterhead={\blank[disable]}` to prevent a page break at this point.  The other points are more complicated and I can only offer a partial solution which requires macro support.  I wrote the macro `\keeptogether{<n>}{<content>}` where `<n>` is the number of lines you want to protect from ever breaking.  The macro simply records `<content>` into a box and splits it after `<n>` lines.  Unfortunately, this might discard `\parskip` within `\vsplit` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463622/how-to-preserve-parskip-in-vsplit)), so no `\setupwhitespace[medium]`, unless you don't care about inconsistent paragraph spacing.

```
\definesymbol[chevron][>]

\setupitemize
  [headstyle=bold,
   afterhead={\blank[disable]}]

\setupitemize
  [1]
  [symbol=chevron]

\define[1]\keeptogether{%
  \dowithnextbox{%
    \setbox\scratchbox=\vsplit\nextbox to #1\lineheight
    \setbox\scratchbox=\vbox{\unvbox\scratchbox}
    \ifdim\dp\scratchbox<\strutdepth
      \dp\scratchbox=\strutdepth
    \fi
    \box\scratchbox
    \unvbox\nextbox
  }\vbox
}

\starttext

\startitemize
  \starthead{Heading One\hfill\normal{1}}

    \samplefile{ward}

  \stophead

  \starthead{Heading Two\hfill\normal{2}}

    \samplefile{ward}

    \samplefile{ward}

  \stophead

  \starthead{Heading Three\hfill\normal{3}}

    \samplefile{knuth}

  \stophead

  \starthead{Heading Four\hfill\normal{4}}

    \startitemize[joinedup,nowhite,after]
    \item Some important point.
    \item \samplefile{jojomayer}
    \item Hmm shouldn't there be whitespace below?
    \stopitemize

    \keeptogether{3}{\samplefile{knuth}}

  \stophead

  \starthead{Heading Five\hfill\normal{5}}

    \samplefile{ward}

    \startitemize[joinedup,nowhite,after]
    \item Some important point.
    \item \samplefile{jojomayer}
    \item Hmm shouldn't there be whitespace below?
    \stopitemize
  \stophead

\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Comment: I really like where this is going, especially the linked question. Instead of placing the `\vbox` it might be better to specify interline penalties within the box only, then unboxing before placement. This would play better with widow and orphan penalties and the builtin paragraph builder.