# How to set a macro to surround `\item` in ConTeXt?

Tags: enumerate, context, itemize

I have an itemized list like this:

```
\starttext
    \startitemize[n]
         \item This is some text.
         \item This is some more text.
         \item This is some yet more text text.
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

How can I assign a custom macro to surround all of the text in the list, it would be equivalent to this:

```
\define[1]\mymacro{Do some stuff #1}

\starttext
    \startitemize[n]
         \item \mymacro{This is some text.}
         \item \mymacro{This is some more text.}
         \item \mymacro{This is some yet more text text.}
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Basically I need to do some settings to the itemize such that the equivalent of placing `\mymacro{}` around every item in the itemized list.

How can I get a macro to surround `\item`'s text in ConTeXt?

Comment: Use the `\startitem…\stopitem` syntax instead of plain `\item` and then use the usual hooks.

Comment: @TeXnician what hooks do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, can't elaborate right now. Other approach: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/item (there's an example by Wolfgang using a custom item command).

Comment: See the first example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463045 for how to wrap an item. It requires a different syntax though.

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice by TeXnician and the correction by Henri Menke, this seems to work in your case:

```
\define[1]\mymacro{Do some stuff #1 Do some more stuff}

\setupitemize[command=\mymacro]

\starttext
    \startitemize[n]
         \item{This is some text.}
         \item{This is some more text.}
         \item{This is some yet more text text.}
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

It might be better to define your own itemization, not to change the default one if you want to use that one as well. This could work:

```
\define[1]\mymacro{Do some stuff #1 Do some more stuff}

\defineitemgroup[myitems]
\setupitemgroup[myitems][each][n]
\setupitemgroup[myitems][each][command=\mymacro]

\starttext
    \startitemize[n]
     \item This is some text.
     \item This is some more text.
     \item This is some yet more text text.
    \stopitemize

    \startmyitems
     \item{This is some text.}
     \item{This is some more text.}
     \item{This is some yet more text text.}
    \stopmyitems
\stoptext
```

Comment: You'll still need braces around each `\item`. To see what I mean try `\define[1]\mymacro{before #1 oeps}`

Comment: Thanks, updated. (I first wanted to add an answer just to have an answer. I make this community wiki...)